# Uploading large file to SharePoint with metadata using Microsoft Graph SDK for java

Tags: java, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-sdks

Uploading a large file to SharePoint Online (Document library) via the MS Graph SDK (Java) works for me, but adding also metadata on an upload seems to be hard

I tried the to add the metadata inside the **DriveItemUploadableProperties**, because I didn't find any hints where the right place should be

```
DriveItemUploadableProperties value = new DriveItemUploadableProperties();
value.additionalDataManager().put("Client",  new JsonPrimitive("Test ABC"));
    
var driveItemCreateUploadSessionParameterSet = DriveItemCreateUploadSessionParameterSet.newBuilder().withItem(value);

UploadSession uploadSession = graphClient.sites(SPValues.SITE_ID).lists(SPValues.LIST_ID).drive().root().itemWithPath(path).createUploadSession(driveItemCreateUploadSessionParameterSet.build()).buildRequest().post();
LargeFileUploadTask<DriveItem> largeFileUploadTask = new LargeFileUploadTask<>(uploadSession, graphClient, fileStream, streamSize, DriveItem.class);
    
LargeFileUploadResult<DriveItem> upload = largeFileUploadTask.upload(customConfig);
```

This results in a **400 : Bad Request** response

How can I add metadata on an upload the right way?

Comment: Please, may you share more details or inner message from HTTP error message? For example: [Compression Handler](https://microsoftgraph.github.io/msgraph-sdk-design/middleware/CompressionHandler.html)

Comment: can share the code for this , im having trouble uploading big files to sharepoint via java ?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, you cannot add metadata while uploading to Sharepoint. You will have to make two separate requests, one to upload the file, and one to add additional metadata to the file that you just uploaded.

Before adding your own custom metadata, you must register the facets / schema to OneDrive. Refer to this doc :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/concepts/custom-metadata-facets?view=odsp-graph-online

But you should be aware that because custom facets are a feature in preview, at the time of this post you have to literally contact an MS email and get the custom facet manually approved, there is no automatic API to do this unfortunately.

If you somehow manage to get the custom facet approved :

**DriveItemUploadableProperties** has preset fields such as filename, size, etc. meant to represent the upload task and basic details about the file, there are no options to add additional metadata to it. Refer to the documentation for **DriveItemUploadableProperties** :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/driveitemuploadableproperties?view=graph-rest-1.0

I assume that when you say, "Uploading a large file to SharePoint Online (Document library) via the MS Graph SDK (Java) works for me", you are able to successfully upload the file and obtain the item ID in the response from the uploaded file. You can use the item ID to update the metadata of the file via a second request. Specifically, refer to the update driveitem here :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider( authProvider ).buildClient();

DriveItem driveItem = new DriveItem();
driveItem.name = "new-file-name.docx";

graphClient.me().drive().items("{item-id}")
    .buildRequest()
    .patch(driveItem);
```

Edit :

As additional information, you can use a ListItem rather than a DriveItem resource and input custom fields there. However, you should be aware that unlike custom facets that I mention above, custom metadata stored in these fields are **not indexed** and is not meant to be queried / filtered on large datasets, which is the most common use case for metadata. When querying for these fields you must include the

```
Prefer : HonorNonIndexedQueriesWarningMayFailRandomly
```

in the request header, and as the header says you should be aware that the query may fail randomly in large datasets.

Comment: Do you know how to add metadata in with a second request?

Comment: @Bjop I would extend the DriveItem object with the custom facet metadata that you want to add. You can see all the base facets here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/resources/driveitem?view=odsp-graph-online 
If you look at facets like "image" for example, it is an object with "width" and "height" in it. Similarly if I created a facet called "Contoso" which is an object that contains "Oil" and "Price", I would extend the DriveItem object respectively with that facet model and send the patch request. The difficult part is getting the custom facet manually approved.

Comment: It just needs to be a string

Comment: @Bjop The schema for the facet can just be a string.

Comment: I made a question of it will you please have a look at it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73205229/ms-graph-api-adding-metadata-to-sharepoint-file