# MS graph api adding metadata to SharePoint file

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api

I would like to add metadata to a SharePoint file. When i search the internet I find solutions like

```java
graphClient.sites("{id}").drives("{id}").items("{id}").buildRequest().fields().patch(driveItem);
```

But I get the following message
`Cannot resolve method 'fields' in 'DriveItemRequest'`
When looking in the java doc, this method does not exitst.

An other solution is:

```java
var fieldValueSet = new FieldValueSet();
fieldValueSet.additionalDataManager().put("Soort", new JsonPrimitive("Invoice"));
graphClient.sites("{id}").drives("{id}").items("{id}").buildRequest().patch(fieldValueSet );
```

But now I got the following message
`Required type: DriveItem, Provided: FieldValueSet`

Sommething else i tried:

```java
FieldValueSet fieldValueSet =  new FieldValueSet();
FieldValueSetRequest fieldValueSetRequest = graphClient.sites("{id}").lists("{id}").items({id}).fields().buildRequest();
fieldValueSet.additionalDataManager().put("Soort", new JsonPrimitive("new soort"));

return fieldValueSetRequest.patch(fieldValueSet);
```

Now I get a 400 back `invalidRequest Error message: Invalid request PATCH`

I also tried to extend `DriveItem` with my own property

```java
CustomDriveItem customDriveItem =  new CustomDriveItem();
customDriveItem.soort = "new soort";
return graphClient.sites({id}).drives({id}).items({id}).buildRequest().patch(customDriveItem);
```

The extended class:

```java
public class CustomDriveItem extends DriveItem {
    @SerializedName(value="soort")
    @Expose
    public String soort;

    public CustomDriveItem() {
        super();
    }
}
```

This also gives me a 400 back `invalidRequest Error message: Invalid request PATCH`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `driveItem` object does not have `fields` - you'll need to transition to a `listItem` to access it. You could try:

```
var fieldValueSet = new FieldValueSet();
fieldValueSet.additionalDataManager().put("Soort", new JsonPrimitive("Invoice"));
graphClient.sites("{id}").drives("{id}").items("{id}").listItem().fields().buildRequest().patch(fieldValueSet );
```

Comment: @Bjop FYI, listitem fields cannot reliably be filtered and queried. This is the reason why Onedrive custom facets exist. When querying for listitem via a column, make sure you include  'Prefer: HonorNonIndexedQueriesWarningMayFailRandomly' in the request header, and as the header says, the request may fail randomly on large datasets. I didn't mention this in my other answer because the most common use case is to be able to filter / search via metadata, and listitem columns are not reliable. I will update my other answer.